# Installing compatible library in python

Tags: python, pip

Is there any standard way to find out the compatible latest version of library that I want to install using pip?

I want to install `matplotlib` on `python 2.6.6` and whenever I use pip it starts downloading the latest version **3.2.1** which is not compatible for `python 2.6`.

Am I missing something here ? I know `conda` can be used to solve package dependency but I don't have that liberty on any servers.

Comment: any particular reason why you're using python 2.6?

Comment: My company is yet to realise it's time to move on.

Answer (score -1):

The `pip` and `python` are two programs. The default `pip` program run by you cli maybe not matching the python you are using.

To install the correct `pip` probably you need to review the install guide of the python and set proper pip in the path for your shell.

Or there is another simple way to work around. Since pip is just a python module like any others you can call it in the module way:

```
python -m pip install --user matplotlib 

or 

python3 -m pip install --user matplotlib
```

If python complains `pip` module not found, then the python you are using has no pip installed. You have to install it first.

Comment: Well, when I provide a compatible version in pip install matplotlib==X.X it correctly installs into python.